# How do I find the equation from a transformed exponential graph?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to get the equation of
$$2f(x-5) + 1.5$$
where
$f(x) = 2^x$.

I have tried using algebra but I always end up with 2 unknown variables

How do I figure anything out when we have the horizontal translations with a vertical stretch?

I tried $$y=b^x + 1.5$$ and $$y=ab^{x-4} +1.5$$

Comment: hello. Why are you writing $a$? There is no $a$ in this story. Unless, you wish to define $a$.

Comment: Ummm.... $2 \cdot 2^{x-5} + 1.5$?

Answer (score 1):

Good, I can see you noticed $$2 \cdot 2^{x-5} = 2^{x-4},$$ but you seem confused in adding the parameters(?) $a$ and $b$.

Now add the 1.5 for
$$g(x) = 2^{x-4} + 1.5,$$
and that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion might come from the fact that the same variable $x$ is used both to denote :

- the input of the function $g(x)= x-5$

and

- the input of the function $f(x)= 2^x$.

The process is as follows:

(1) function $g$ takes as  input some number  $x$ and gives the output $x+5$

(2) call this output $X$

(3) function $f$ takes the output X ( = x+5) and gives the output $2^{X} = 2^{x+5}$

(4) another function, call it $h$ takes this last output as input and multplies it by $2$.

(5) a last function adds $1.5$ to this last output, call ths function  $j$.

So your function is $j(h(f(g(x))))$ ( " $j$ of $h$ of $f$ of $g$ of $x$ ").

Each function is a function of " something" that can be denoted by $x$ , but this " something" is not the same thing at each stage of the process.